# How to solve the issue faced in Automated billing system

Tags: android

The idea is to create an automated supermarket billing system. My mobile App will deduct amount from customers bank account when they pick a product and scan its QR code but at the exit of my shop I will validate customer billing information which will be send through Wi-Fi from my App. The issue is How Am I supposed to corner the one who hasn't authenticated billing information or provided the incorrect billing info.

Comment: Welcome to SO, This question is way too broad. Please take a minute to read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and maybe [Writing the perfect question.](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and try writing a better question, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comments so adding an answer.

There are many ways to handle payments POS (Point of Sale, I am hoping this is what you are asking).

You can integrate your application with some Payment Gateways and build your app with including their SDK. Payments will be handled by them. Once you try to charge a customer using his details (For example - using his credit card and password) the payment gateway server will send you a response whether it is success or failure.

If you can be a little specific about what you need, I can give you specific answers.

Thank You,
Hariharan A